# stop render until useEffect is done

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, react-hooks

I am setting the default access level

But the problem here is that when the access level is changed in the useEffect, the page is rendered with the default access level.
How can I hold the rendering of the page until the use effect is finished?

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element {
  const [role, setRole] = useState('candidate');
  const auth = nookies.get()["auth"];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth) {
      const parsedUser = JSON.parse(auth);
      const { role_id } = parsedUser as unknown as CookieInfo;
      if (role_id) {
        const current_user_role = roles.find((x) => x.id === role_id)?.name || 'Candidate';
        const aclRole = current_user_role.replace(' ', '').toLowerCase();
        console.log('aclRole', aclRole, role_id, current_user_role);
        setRole(aclRole);
      }
    }
  }, [auth, role])
  console.log('role', role);
  let userId = 0;

if (auth) {
  const parsedUser = JSON.parse(auth);
  userId = parsedUser?.id;
}
  // console.log('');

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
```

I want the rendering to stop until the following variable is called:

```
setRole(aclRole);
```

Comment: That's weird. My assumption is that your pg works in oreder like follows. 
1. <ThemeProvider> renders. 
2. useEffect is fired with auth and role which are initial values. 
3. setRole is fired with "actRole" inside useEffect. 
4. <ThemeProvider> renders. 
5. useEffect is fired again with auth which is same as previous one, but role which is new value. 
6. setRole is fired with "actRole" inside useEffect again. 
7. Finally, <ThemeProvider> renders.

 I wonder what the value of "actRole" is in phase 6 as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a loading state, and if loading is still in progress, return null. This could either be an additional state:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [role, setRole] = useState('candidate');
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... load as before, ending with:
    setLoading(false);
  }, [auth, role]);

  // ...
  if (loading) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
     <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
```

Or possibly the `role` state is enough, it just needs some special value saying not to use it yet. `null` or `undefined` are common choices:

```
const [role, setRole] = useState<string | null>(null);
// ...
if (role === null) {
  return null;
}

return (
   <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
```